# Is this a valid use for blocks in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, colors

In my constructor, I want to create a random color.

Therefore, I need three random 7-bit floats in the range of 0…1 that make up the red, green and blue component of the color. Instead of writing the rather long `random() % 128 / 128.0` three times, I put that in a block:

```
CGFloat (^randFloat)() = ^(){ return random() % 128 / 128.0; };
color = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(randFloat(), randFloat(), randFloat(), .5);
```

Is that a valid way to use blocks?
If not, what would you use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you going to return `randFloat`? Will `randFloat` use any states not separable from the nearby functions (i.e. is `randFloat` a closure)? If not, it's more portable (the iPhone official SDK doesn't support blocks yet, for example) and efficient to create a static function outside of the function:

```
static CGFloat randFloat() {
    return random() % 128 / 128.0;
}
...
color = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(randFloat(), randFloat(), randFloat(), .5);
```

Comment: iPhone OS doesn't support blocks out of the box yet, but you can still use them with PLBlocks.

Comment: No, randFloat will not use any external variables. It is just meant as a shorthand for `random() % 128 / 128`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing *wrong* with using a block that way. I personally wouldn't in this case, since creating a block for the operation actually makes the code longer. But it seems fine in principle. If this function is never used anywhere else, why give it a larger scope than it needs?